# button wont show up in webpage?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I'm tiring to add a search button in main search form but for some odd reason nothing is showing up after I save and refresh, I coded this button exactly the same as another button for this site but it's not made visible, any ideas?  I'm not sure what's wrong with it and really not sure on how it can be fixed, is it the way I have written my code that's causing the problem does anybody see how I can fix it thanks for all your help and suggestions, thanks in advance!

```css
/* color:#00a786 lighter green */
/* color:#005242 dark green for buttons */
/* color:003027 dark green background */




*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html{
      background-color: #fff;
    }

body{
      background: #ede6e6;
      margin:0 auto;
      font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif ;
    }

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
}
li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
}
/* --------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------- */
header{
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(../img/heder_photo_2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  right:-20px;
  left: -20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;

background-attachment: fixed;
position: absolute;
z-index: 80;

}

.row{
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;


}

}
/* --------------------------------TOP-LEFT------------------------------------- */
.top-left{

  float:left;
}
.top-left ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: -80px;
  padding-bottom: 30px

}


/* -------------------------------SOCIAL-LINKS------------------------------------- */
.social-links ul {
display:inline;
padding-left: 150px;

}
.social-links li{
  font-size: 100%;


}

.social-links li:hover,
.social-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}



/* -------------------------------TOP-RIGHT------------------------------------- */
.top-right{
  float:right;

}
.top-right  {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}


.top-right li {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 200;
}
  .top-right li:hover,
  .top-right li:active{
color:#005242;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}


.top-right li:first-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
.top-right li:last-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
/* -------------------------------H1------------------------------------- */

.main-header{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  float:left;

}
.header-text{
  display: inline-block;
}

h1{
font-size: 90%;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;


}
span{
  color:#00a786
}

/* -------------------------------MAIN-NAV------------------------------------ */
.main-nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.main-nav-links{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav-links li:hover,
.main-nav-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;

}
/* -------------------------------MAIN-SECTION------------------------------------ */
.main-section{




}
.main-content{
  text-align: center;


}
.content{
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content h2{

  font-size: 100%;
}

.content p{
  font-size: 60%
}

/* -------------------------------BUTTONS------------------------------------ */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited,
  input[type=submit]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding :10px 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;
    msargin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit]{
    background-color: #00a786;
    border: 1px solid #005242;
    color: #fff;

  }
    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #005242;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

    }


    .search-btn:link,
  .search-btn:visited,
      input[type=submit]{
        display: inline-block;
        padding :10px 30px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        font-size: 60%;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 5px;

        transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;
        msargin-right: 15px;
    }

  .search-btn:link,
  .search-btn:visited,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #00a786;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

      }
      .search-btn:hover,
    .search-btn:active,
        input[type=submit]{
            background-color: #005242;
            border: 1px solid #005242;
            color: #fff;

        }


/* -------------------------------form search------------------------------------ */
    .section-Search{
      background-color: #003027;
      border: 2px solid #003027;
      border-radius: 3px;
      position:relative;
      left:200px;
      right:20px;
      top: 500px;
      height: 30vh;
      width: 600px;
      z-index: 99;

}
   .main-Search{
padding:30px 10px;
  display: inline;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styling.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/fonts/Aileron/">
      <title>Williams Rental Propertie's</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <!--- TOP LEFT-------->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="top-left">
      <ul>
        <li>  <i class="fas fa-phone-volume icon-contact ">(312)343-8748</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-envelope icon-contact">WilliamsRentalProperties</i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--- SOCIAL LINKS-------->
    <div class="social-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </a></i></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--- TOP RIGHT-------->
    <div class="top-right">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fas fa-user "> <a href="#"> Register</i></a></li>
          <li> <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><a href="#">Login</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <!--- main Header-------->

    <div class="main-header">
      <div class="header-text">
        <h1>Williams <span> Rental</span> Properties</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="main-nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Featured List</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> About Us</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Pages</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>

  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Let Us Find You Your Dream Home!</h2>
        <p>Search real estate property records, houses, condos, land and more .
Find property info from the most comprehensive source data.</p>
     <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </header>

  <section class ="section-Search">
    <div class="main-Search">



      <form class="Search" action="index.html" method="post">
        <label for="address"></label>

          <!--- city-------->
        
        <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="keyword,zipcode">

          <!--- city-------->

        <label for="city"></label>
      <select class="city" name="city">
        <option value="city">city</option>
        </select>

          <!--- state------->

        <label for="state"></label>
      <select class="state" name="state-form">
        <option value="state">state</option>

    <!--- search button------->
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">Search</a>

      </select>


      </form>
    </div>


  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your search button is inside a `<select>` tag, that's why it's not showing up. Move it outside the `select` tag and it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is inside `<select>` tag which is incorrect.
Move it outside like this and it should be shown.

```
<!--- state------->

<label for="state"></label>
<select class="state" name="state-form">
  <option value="state">state</option>
</select>

<!--- search button------->
<a class="search-btn" href="#">Search</a>
```